# React unable to focus on div

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to focus on a div when I click on a button like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vankovilija/69z2wepo/54202/). I reduced my problem to the code bellow, where although focus is called on the div object, onFocus is never called. Also `autoFocus` doesn't solve my problem because I want to be able to change focus multiple time after the component did mount.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.my_refs = {};
        this.focusByID.bind(this);
    }

    focusByID(id){
        let myRef = this.my_refs[id];
        if(myRef){
            console.log('focusing on ', id, myRef);
            myRef.focus();
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div
                    id="bigRedDiv"
                    style={{height : 200, width : 200, backgroundColor : 'red'}}
                    ref={(input) => this.my_refs['bigRedDiv'] = input }
                    onFocus={() => console.log('FOCUS IS ON BIG RED DIV')}
                    onClick={() => this.focusByID('bigRedDiv')}
                >
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asmail/69z2wepo/83665/) containing this code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just:

```
...
<div 
    tabIndex="0" //use this attribute
    id="bigRedDiv" 
    style={{height : 200, width : 200, backgroundColor : 'red'}} 
    ref={(input)=> this.my_refs['bigRedDiv'] = input } 
    onFocus={() => console.log('FOCUS IS ON BIG RED DIV')} 
    onClick={() => this.focusByID('bigRedDiv')} >
</div>
...
```

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed tabindex="0" allows elements besides links and form elements to receive keyboard focus, as I just learned it.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to set tabIndex to -1? _tabindex= "-1" removes the element from the navigation sequence, but can be made focusable using javascript._